# How to distingue between inputs inside onCreateInputConnection from WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have an excerpt of my app that loads a HTML - which I do not have any access to change - with three inputs: e-mail, password and a validation code on a WebView. The last one will always be numbers. I want to show the numeric keyboard only for this last input element. I'm doing that by extending a WebView class and overriding this method as shown below:

```
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        BaseInputConnection ic = new BaseInputConnection(this, true);
        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER; // Tells the keyboard to show the number pad
        return ic;
    }
```

Problem is, I do not know which flag I can check in order to differ the three different inputs I have on the HTML, so I can run this code only for the validation code input element. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found anything related to distinguishing between input fields from WebView inside this method `onCreateInputConnection`?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

Capture the before focus event in javascript, store the field id which is about to get focus and then use that value in onCreateInputConnection to make decisions on what type of keyboard to show.

If you don't have access to change the source html you can inject your own javascript to set the focusin handler.

For example;

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView
{
    protected String m_szFocusInputID = "";

    public void onStartLoad()
    {
        WebSettings oWebSettings = getSettings();
        oWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ... 
        m_oClient = new WebViewClientEx();
        setWebViewClient(m_oClient);
        ...
        addJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge( ), "MyApp");
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html"); 
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo oAttrs)
    {
        InputConnection oConn = super.onCreateInputConnection(oAttrs);

        if ("someid".compareTo(m_szFocusInputID) == 0)
        {
            oAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;
        }
        return oConn;
    }


    private class WebViewClientEx extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView oView, String szUrl)
        {
            evaluateJavascript("$('#myinput1').focusin(function() { MyApp.onFocusIn(this.id); });", null);      
        }
    }


    public class JSBridge extends Object
    {
     ...
        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void onFocusIn(String szFocusInputID)
        {
            m_szFocusInputID = szFocusInputID;
        }
    }   
}
```